# R Conditional calculation and row flags within groups

Tags: r

I am currently using R.  I have three columns in which I need to identify duplicates.

This is the dataframe that I am using:

```
df1 <-data.frame(ID_NUMBER = c(990,50000,52000,764000,764000,764000,1420000,1420000,1470000,1470000,2176000,2176000,2401000,2401000,2667000,2667000,3519000,3721000,3721000,4654000,4654000,4685000), 
     CalNumber = c(0,1126.61,1152.24,26900.12,26900.2,26910,50673.98,50674.31,52161.18,52161.73,77743.17,77743.7,85593.97,85594.42,94854.76,94855,124033.46,130973.56,130973.59,162935.73,162935.85,163446.89),

     Date = c('8/8/2013' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/8/2013')) 



   ID_NUMBER    CalNumber        Date
     990      0           8/8/2013 0:00
     50000    1126.61     8/16/2008 0:00
     52000    1152.24     8/8/2013 0:00
     764000   26900.12    8/8/2013 0:00
     764000   26900.2     8/16/2008 0:00
     764000   26910       8/16/2008
    1420000   50673.98    8/16/2008 0:00
    1420000   50674.31    8/8/2013 0:00
    1470000   52161.18    8/16/2008 0:00
    1470000   52161.73    8/8/2013 0:00
    2176000   77743.17    8/16/2008 0:00
    2176000   77743.7     8/8/2013 0:00
    2401000   85593.97    8/16/2008 0:00
    2401000   85594.42    8/8/2013 0:00
    2667000   94854.76    8/16/2008 0:00
    2667000   94855       8/8/2013 0:00
    3519000   124033.46   8/8/2013 0:00
    3721000   130973.56   8/8/2013 0:00
    3721000   130973.59   8/16/2008 0:00
    4654000   162935.73   8/16/2008 0:00
    4654000   162935.85   8/8/2013 0:00
    4685000   163446.89   8/8/2013 0:00
```

Duplicates are identified as follows:  If the ID_NUMBER is not unique, then subtract the record right below for the ID_Number group.  If the delta between the next is  <= 1 then it is considered a duplicate.  The record that takes precedence would be the Maximum date for that group. That would become primary and second would be flagged as a secondary group.   My final result set would have two new flags: isNew and isPrimary. If a duplicate does not exist, then it is considered a new first time record.    So isNew would be 'Y' and isPrimary would be 'Y' for non duplicate records. I hope the example of what the result would look like below, explains my ramble a little better. I'm too new R so I don't know where to start..so any suggestions or pointers are greatly appreciated.

```
   ID_NUMBER    CalNumber   Date     CalcDiff       IsNew   isPrimary
     990      0           8/8/2013           --          Y         Y
     50000    1126.61     8/16/2008          --          Y         Y
     52000    1152.24     8/8/2013           --          Y         Y
     764000   26900.12    8/8/2013           --          N         Y
     764000   26900.2     8/16/2008          .08         N         N
     764000   26910           8/16/2008          9.8         Y         Y 
    1420000   50673.98    8/16/2008          --          N         N
    1420000   50674.31    8/8/2013           .33         N         Y
    1470000   52161.18    8/16/2008          --          N         N
    1470000   52161.73    8/8/2013           .55         N         Y
    2176000   77743.17    8/16/2008          --          N         Y
    2176000   77743.7     8/8/2013           .53         N         N 
    2401000   85593.97    8/16/2008          --          N         N
    2401000   85594.42    8/8/2013           .45         N         Y 
    2667000   94854.76    8/16/2008          --          N         N   
    2667000   94855          8/8/2013            .24         N         Y
    3519000   124033.46   8/8/2013           --          Y         Y     
    3721000   130973.56   8/8/2013           --          N         Y
    3721000   130973.59   8/16/2008          .03         N         N  
    4654000   162935.73   8/16/2008          --          Y         Y 
    4654000   162936.85   8/8/2013           1.12        Y         Y  
    4685000   163446.89   8/8/2013            --         Y         Y
```

Comment: It is a little difficult to follow the conditions. Could you please explain, for example how did you get the values of `IsNew` and `isPrimary` for ID **764000**?

Comment: First I subtracted 26900.2 from the second record 26900.12, that gave me .08.  Since the value is <1 that means that these records are duplicate of eachother.   Isnew is 'N' because they are duplicates.  The isPrimary = 'Y' becomes the one with the highest date, 08/2013.  the second one becomes isPrimary='N'.  the third record, I subtracted from the previous, which produced 9.8.  This is not a duplicate because the delta is greater than 1.  so Isnew would be 'Y' and isPrimary  would be 'Y'.   I hope this helps

Comment: I don't think your expected results are correct. Consider record `2401000`. The maximum date is `8/8/2013`, so shouldn't that be the primary? Also, check out the second from last record. In the expect result, the `CalNumber` is different to in your data frame, `df1`.

Comment: yes, sorry, fat finger error.  the 8/8/2013 should be the primary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution requires `dplyr` and `magrittr` (for the compound assignment pipe). First, I define the data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ID_NUMBER = c(990,50000,52000,764000,764000,764000,1420000,1420000,1470000,1470000,2176000,2176000,2401000,2401000,2667000,2667000,3519000,3721000,3721000,4654000,4654000,4685000), 
             CalNumber = c(0,1126.61,1152.24,26900.12,26900.2,26910,50673.98,50674.31,52161.18,52161.73,77743.17,77743.7,85593.97,85594.42,94854.76,94855,124033.46,130973.56,130973.59,162935.73,162936.85,163446.89),
             Date = c('8/8/2013' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/16/2008' ,'8/8/2013' ,'8/8/2013'))
```

Here, I convert your `Date` to a date. Then, I group by `ID_NUMBER` and calculate the differences between neighbouring rows. I then apply your criteria using `case_when` to determine `IsNew`. Finally, I group by `ID_NUMBER` again as well as `IsNew` and check for the most recent date.

```
df %<>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>% 
  group_by(ID_NUMBER) %>% 
  mutate(CalcDiff = c(NA, diff(CalNumber))) %>% 
  mutate(IsNew = case_when(
    n() > 1 & is.na(CalcDiff) & lead(CalcDiff)[1] <=1 ~ "N",
    n() > 1 & is.na(CalcDiff) & lead(CalcDiff)[1] > 1 ~ "Y",
    n() > 1 & CalcDiff <= 1 ~ "N",
    n() > 1 & CalcDiff >1 ~ "Y",
    TRUE ~ "Y"
  )) %>% 
  group_by(ID_NUMBER, IsNew) %>% 
  mutate(IsPrimary = case_when(
    Date == max(Date) & IsNew == "N" ~ "Y",
    Date != max(Date) & IsNew == "N" ~ "N",
    TRUE ~ "Y"
  ))
```

Results:

```
# A tibble: 22 x 6
# Groups:   ID_NUMBER, IsNew [14]
# ID_NUMBER CalNumber Date       CalcDiff IsNew IsPrimary
# <dbl>     <dbl> <date>        <dbl> <chr> <chr>    
# 1       990         0  2013-08-08  NA      Y     Y        
# 2      50000     1127. 2008-08-16  NA      Y     Y        
# 3      52000     1152. 2013-08-08  NA      Y     Y        
# 4     764000    26900. 2013-08-08  NA      N     Y        
# 5     764000    26900. 2008-08-16   0.08   N     N        
# 6     764000    26910  2008-08-16   9.80   Y     Y        
# 7    1420000    50674. 2008-08-16  NA      N     N        
# 8    1420000    50674. 2013-08-08   0.330  N     Y        
# 9    1470000    52161. 2008-08-16  NA      N     N        
# 10   1470000    52162. 2013-08-08   0.55   N     Y        
# 11   2176000    77743. 2008-08-16  NA      N     N        
# 12   2176000    77744. 2013-08-08   0.530  N     Y        
# 13   2401000    85594. 2008-08-16  NA      N     N        
# 14   2401000    85594. 2013-08-08   0.450  N     Y        
# 15   2667000    94855. 2008-08-16  NA      N     N        
# 16   2667000    94855  2013-08-08   0.24   N     Y        
# 17   3519000   124033. 2013-08-08  NA      Y     Y        
# 18   3721000   130974. 2013-08-08  NA      N     Y        
# 19   3721000   130974. 2008-08-16   0.0300 N     N        
# 20   4654000   162936. 2008-08-16  NA      Y     Y        
# 21   4654000   162937. 2013-08-08   1.12   Y     Y        
# 22   4685000   163447. 2013-08-08  NA      Y     Y
```